# Can openidbutton be used with a popup window?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm using the openidbutton to allow users to log into my site with google, yahoo, etc.
When they click the button it redirects to the yahoo page, then redirects back to my page once authenticated.

All that is working great, but the problem is there is no going back once the button is clicked.

So, if they click the yahoo button and it redirects to yahoo's authentication, the back button is now disabled, and they can't change their mind and return to my site without closing the browser.

Here is my code

```
<rp:OpenIdButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/yahoo.png" Text="Login with Yahoo!" ID="yahooLoginButton" 
                Identifier="https://me.yahoo.com/" ReturnToUrl="~/OpenIDComplete.aspx" OnLoggingIn="OpenIdLogin1_LoggingIn" OnLoggedIn="OpenIdLogin1_LoggedIn">
                <Extensions>
                    <sreg:ClaimsRequest Email="Require" FullName="Request" />
                </Extensions>
            </rp:OpenIdButton>
```

What I've seen and want to reproduce, is when the click the button, it opens a new window that's only used for authentication, then it closes and redirects the parent to the logged in section.

I can't seem to find anyway to do this.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: use jquery or javascript

Comment: do you have a jquery plugin that you could recommend?

Comment: If you're not going to try to be helpful, I would rather you not comment at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jQuery Fancybox version 2 (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) for my login popup, it works very nicely. I've not actually gone to yahoo and back though but other redirects to pages just go to the popup until I close it.

Then you can reload the main page when you close the popup with

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterClose : function() {
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
});
```